# Getting median value of attribute for duplicate polygons and dropping duplicates using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, aggregation, geodataframe, median

I have a `DataFrame` that resulted from spatially joining a digital elevation map with a square grid map.

[image]

This unexpectedly resulted in duplicate rows where two rows will have the same `"geometry"` but a different `"Elevation"` value.

How do I get the median of `"Elevation"` for each unique `"geometry"`? I'm new to GeoPandas, so I tried the traditional methods of aggregating a `DataFrame`, but found that `"geometry"` cannot be operated with the `groupby()` function.

```py
mrkna_grid.groupby("geometry")['Elevation'].median()
```

I have also tried using the `dissolve()` function, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly because the number of rows were reduced to just seventy (70) as opposed to the original two thousand (2000) before the spatial join.

```py
mrkna_grid.dissolve(by="Elevation", aggfunc="median")
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the duplicate geometries?

Comment: @BERA no, I just need every unique `"geometry"` and the median of all its `"Elevation"` associated with said `"geometry"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'layer'* with its attribute table, see the image below.

[image: input]

The expected result of [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is:

```
Polygon 1 | 4
Polygon 2 | 7
Polygon 3 | 15
```

Using one of the following code:

### Solution #1 includes Pandas/GeoPandas native [`DataFrame.median()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.median.html)

```py
import geopandas as gpd

path_to_layer = "C:/Documents/Python Scripts/median/layer.shp"
layer = gpd.read_file(path_to_layer)

layer_ = layer.groupby(layer["geometry"].to_wkt())['Elevation'].median().reset_index(name='MedianElev')
layer_['geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(layer_['index'])
layer_.drop(['index'], inplace=True, axis=1)

output = gpd.GeoDataFrame(layer_, geometry='geometry')
output = output.set_crs(layer.crs)
output.to_file("output.shp")
```

### Solution #2 includes Python's [`statistics.median()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median)

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from statistics import median

path_to_layer = "C:/Documents/Python Scripts/median/layer.shp"
layer = gpd.read_file(path_to_layer)

layer['geom_wkt'] = layer['geometry'].to_wkt()

layer_ = layer.groupby('geom_wkt')['Elevation'].apply(list).reset_index(name='ElevationList')
layer_['median'] = layer_['ElevationList'].apply(lambda x: median(x))
layer_['geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(layer_['geom_wkt'])
layer_.drop(['geom_wkt', 'ElevationList'], inplace=True, axis=1)

output = gpd.GeoDataFrame(layer_, geometry='geometry')
output = output.set_crs(layer.crs)
output.to_file("output.shp")
```

it is possible to achieve the following output:

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Converting a column of Polygons from string to GeoPandas geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433138/converting-a-column-of-polygons-from-string-to-geopandas-geometry)
- [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)
- [How to properly apply a lambda function into a pandas data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428218/how-to-properly-apply-a-lambda-function-into-a-pandas-data-frame-column)
- [GeoPandas | Managing Projection](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/projections.html#managing-projections)

Comment: Thank you. One question though: the code above returns a dataframe that only has `"geometry"` and `"Elevation"`.  How would you hypothetically retain other attributes?

Comment: I will probably do the join on e.g. the `"geom_wkt"` attribute. What kind of attributes would you like to retain? Can you share a piece of your data?

Comment: The full picture of the DataFrame in the OP has attributes X, Y and Z (for brevity) alongside the shown `"geometry"` and `"Elevation"`.